# RedirectRoute + strict_slash = KeyError

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

http://mysite.com/cn - OK

http://mysite.com/cn/ - Error

**KeyError: 'Missing argument "0" to build URI.'**

I do have only one route. Please help...

```
class MyHome(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, language='en'):
    buf = 'hello world at %s' % (language,)
    self.response.write(buf)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    routes.DomainRoute(r'<:(localhost|mysite\.com|www\.mysite\.com)>', [
      routes.RedirectRoute(r'/<:(en|bm|my|cn|zh)>', handler=MyHome, strict_slash=True,  name='Home'),
    ]),
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `r'/<language:...` instead of `r'/<:...` for your Routes